# Solving unknown powers for a super quadratic ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\left|\dfrac xa\right|^m + \left|\dfrac yb\right|^n = 1$$

if $x$, $a$, $y$, $b$ are known, how do you solve for $m$ and $n$?

Thank you.

Comment: Can $x$, $y$ be zero? Can $x = a$? Can $y = b$? Are you only considering $m$, $n$ integers?

Comment: If you are considering m and n to be anything, there exists infinite solutions. Since I'm not sure if there are more restrictions on m and n, I don't want to give a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

$A^m+B^n=1\iff A^m=1-B^n\iff m=\log_A(1-B^n)=\dfrac{\ln(1-B^n)}{\ln A}\iff$ for every *n* there's an *m*, as long as $1-B^n>0$.