# Superellipse - Solving for powers of the equation

Tags: geometry

I wonder if you could help with the following problem:

I have aircraft fuselage sections which i would like to fit the nearest super-ellipse.
I only have to work in the first quadrant, i.e. there are no complex numbers involved, so that the general equation may be written as:

$$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|^m + \left|\frac{y}{b}\right|^n = 1$$

The curve starts at $x=a$, $y=0$ and ends at $x=0$, $y=b$.
I need to define any two points within these limits through which the curve must pass.
In other words, my super-ellipse must pass through these two points:

$\left|\frac{x_1}{a}\right|^m + \left|\frac{y_1}{b}\right|^n = 1$

$\left|\frac{x_2}{a}\right|^m +\left|\frac{y_2}{b}\right|^n = 1$

How do I solve for $m$ and $n$?

Your help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Dragan

from Cape Town

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618729/solving-unknown-powers-for-a-super-quadratic-ellipse

Comment: I have already provided an answer to the post linked in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $p=x_1/a,q=y_1/b,r=x_2/a,s=y_2/b.$ By isolating the terms involving $n,$ taking logarithms, and dividing to eliminate $n,$ we get
$$\ln s\ln(1-p^m)=\ln q \ln(1−r^m).$$
I would try Newton--Raphson to solve this for $x=m$: Let
$$f(x):=\ln q\ln(1-r^x)-\ln s\ln(1-p^x),$$so that$$f'(x)=\dfrac{\ln q\ln r}{1-r^{-x}}-\dfrac{\ln s\ln p}{1-p^{-x}}.$$
Start with $x_0=\frac12$ (say) and iterate $x_{j+1}=x_j−f(x_j)/f′(x_j)$ ($j=0,1,...$) with the target $f(x_j)→0$ as $j$ increases. This should converge well in a few steps. The method for $n$ is similar.

Comment: There obviously isn't an analytic solution. n could be derived by substitution once m is determined.

Comment: I wonder if an approximation can be made as i only need an accuracy of two or even one decimal place for m and n.

Comment: @DraganIgnjatovic: I doubt whether you could do better than Newton--Raphson. It typically gives quite good approximations with two iterations, and more than three are rarely needed. The above calculation could practically be carried out on a hand calculator. I have added details for $f'(x)$.